# ¿Cómo enviar un post a un este servidor web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, webservice

Entrego el código que llevo pero me genera error no puedo enviar datos a este servicio web alguien que me ayude , el primero es el código que manda Postman y por hay me e guiado pero no puedo consumirlo ayuda

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": " ",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "988d19f6-4555-484a-aeab-c8c27fe8ea87"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\n\t\"auth_key\": \"ffa07465e5af0a0f69d776e3a288dea1\",\n\t\"entity_number\": \"4006\",\n\t\"contact_identification\": \"123555555\",\n\t\"contact_name\": \"juan PEREZ\",\n\t\"contact_email\": \"juan@email.com\",\n\t\"contact_phone\": \"9999999\",\n\t\"contact_fax\": \"9999999\",\n\t\"contact_address\": \"CALLE 33# 23-43\",\n\t\"city_name\": \"Bogota\",\n\t\"contact_position_name\": \"DIRECTOR\",\n\t\"description\": \"CASO REGISTRADO POR EL USUARIO\"\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html lang="es">
 
<head>
<title>Titulo de la web</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="alternate" title="Pozolería RSS" type="application/rss+xml" href="/feed.rss" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
    </header>

 <div id="resultado_1"></div>

 <div id="resultado_1"></div>

   <div class="container" id="informacion">
    <form action="procesar.php" method="post" name="frm">
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">identificacion</label>
       <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="clave" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputAddress">cargo</label>
    <input name="cargo" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="cargo">
    </div>
       <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">identificacion</label>
       <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="idnt" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputAddress">cargo</label>
    <input name="cargo" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="cargo">
    </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <label for="inputAddress">Nombre</label>
             <input name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Nombre">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
    
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Telefono</label>
       <input name="tel" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Telefono">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputAddress">Fax</label>
    <input name="fax" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Fax">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Direccion</label>
    <input type="text" name="dir" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label  for="inputCity">Ciudad</label>
      <input name="ciudad" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
    <label  for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Descripción</label>
    <textarea name="desp" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
    
  </div>
  
 <button type="button" id="idBoton" class="btn btn-primary" >envio</button>
</form>
  
</div>
<div class="notificacion"></div>
    <footer>
        
    </footer>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#idBoton').click(function(){
           $ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            type : "POST",  
            ContentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/",
            data : JSON.stringinfy({clave: $('auth_key').val() , cedula: $('entity_number').val() ,  idnt: $('contact_identification').val() , name: $('contact_name').val() , Email: $('contact_email').val() , Telefono: $('contact_phone').val() , fax: $('contact_fax').val() , dir: $('contact_address').val() , ciudad: $('city_name').val() ,cargo: $('contact_position_name').val() ,desp: $('"description').val() }),
            success : function(data){
              $('.notificacion').html("<p>" + data.d + "<p>" );
            },
            error: function() {
              alert (" error")
            }
           
         
           });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo visto en tu data le envías un json el cual tiene mal el dato
Ademas de la función stringify()

```
desp:$('"description').val() // doble comillas de mas
```

.

```
data : JSON.stringify(
    {  
       clave:$('auth_key').val(),
       cedula:$('entity_number').val(),
       idnt:$('contact_identification').val(),
       name:$('contact_name').val(),
       Email:$('contact_email').val(),
       Telefono:$('contact_phone').val(),
       fax:$('contact_fax').val(),
       dir:$('contact_address').val(),
       ciudad:$('city_name').val(),
       cargo:$('contact_position_name').val(),
       desp:$('"description').val() // doble comillas de mas
    });
```

Reemplaza la función por

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#idBoton').click(function(){
           $ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            type : "POST",  
            ContentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/",
            data : JSON.stringify({clave: $('auth_key').val() , cedula: $('entity_number').val() ,  idnt: $('contact_identification').val() , name: $('contact_name').val() , Email: $('contact_email').val() , Telefono: $('contact_phone').val() , fax: $('contact_fax').val() , dir: $('contact_address').val() , ciudad: $('city_name').val() ,cargo: $('contact_position_name').val() ,desp: $('description').val() }),
            success : function(data){
              $('.notificacion').html("<p>" + data.d + "<p>" );
            },
            error: function() {
              alert (" error")
            }


           });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: no funciona , creo que es algo estructural

Answer (score -1):

Uncaught TypeError: JSON.stringinfy is not a function

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#idBoton').click(function(){
           $.ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            type : "POST",  
            ContentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/",
            data : JSON.stringinfy({clave: $('auth_key').val() , cedula: $('entity_number').val() ,  idnt: $('contact_identification').val() , name: $('contact_name').val() , Email: $('contact_email').val() , Telefono: $('contact_phone').val() , fax: $('contact_fax').val() , dir: $('contact_address').val() , ciudad: $('city_name').val() ,cargo: $('contact_position_name').val() ,desp: $('description').val() }),
            success : function(data){
              $('.notificacion').html("<p>" + data.d + "<p>" );
            },
            error: function() {
              alert (" error")
            }


           });
        return false;
    });
});
```

no funciona , si habia un eror pero no funciona

Comment: allí edite la respuesta, tienes que cambiar el nombre de 'data : JSON.stringinfy' a 'data : JSON.stringify'

Comment: no uses el espacio de respuestas para hacer aclaraciones, para eso esta la zona de comentarios

Comment: es algo que no logro ver de la estructura